# Percy - Cypress - Error: Could not find browser revision 756035. Run "npm install" or "yarn install" to download a browser binary

Tags: cypress

Im trying to set up a simple visual test with cypress and Percy.

Following the tutorial I installed percy as part of my cypress package, however when I attempt to run.

*npx percy exec -- cypress run*. I am met with the message:

**Error: Could not find browser revision 756035. Run "npm install" or "yarn install" to download a browser binary.**

Anyone else had this issue?

May be worth noting, when I run npx cypress run, the tests run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong with `npm install` process, most likely the decompress failed which does not return a error.

Easiest way is to remove node_modules and install again.